"Vertex matrix is empty" issue in pymeshlab during "boolean" operation
I tried to perform triangular boolean operation and found post here:
Boolean geometry subtraction of 3D meshes
I use exactly the same command blunova posted below:
import pymeshlab

bunny_path = "bunny.ply"
sphere_path = "sphere.ply"

ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()
ms.load_new_mesh(bunny_path)
ms.load_new_mesh(sphere_path)
ms.generate_boolean_intersection()

however, python shown error like below:
pymeshlab.pmeshlab.PyMeshLabException: Failed to apply filter: generate_boolean_intersectionDetails: Error while creating mesh: Vertex matrix is empty.

I'm sure the surface read successfully because I can use current_mesh to query the vertices matrix.
I looked into the documentation of pymeshlab:
https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#generate_boolean_intersection
and seems it needs additional inputs, I'm not sure if there are some upgrade in the recent version.
I'm very new in python, I tried my best until here, could anyone give me any suggestions?
additional information provided here:
version of python is: 3.11.10
version of pymeshlab: 2022.2.post3
Thanks!
expect to find why the sample code not work, maybe it is caused by version upgrade?
